# Does slicing a design in PS create bad code?

Tags: html

I am a beginning programmer and I really want to have good habits and practices.  I have yet to slice up a PSD and code it.  Is this a bad practice?  I have heard it creates bad code that had to be fixed anyway so why do it?  I want to create clean code even if it takes longer.  Just wondering if it is as bad as I have heard.  Are there advantages to doing it this way?  Do I need to learn this skill to make good sites?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are very large, then sometimes slicing them into pieces and generating the right HTML that lines up all the pieces can be a better user experience.  These days, this seems to matter more for those on very slow links (like dial-up) or very poor links (lots of errors) and less for those on typical internet links unless the images are very large.

Overall, slicing images is more overhead for the browser (more HTML, more separate image request for both client and server) so it's only beneficial when specifically needed to solve a problem.  I would not do it by default unless you had a specific problem you were trying to solve with the image slicing.

Comment: I do not really want to do but was wondering how to handle a big background image that covers the whole page.  Is this an instance to use it?  Do professionals use slicing alot?  Just trying to get a feel if it is a bad practice that I do not need to learn in order to be successful.

Comment: Since it's trivial to implement it without slicing, I would implement it that way until you find you have a problem that might be solved with slicing.  Many, many sites use large background images that are not sliced.  I would not implement slicing until you thinking you actually need it.

Comment: Do you slice in PS for anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your background image shouldn't be a very complex image and if it is try to make it as optimized as possible so the load time is efficient for slower downloads.  As for slicing I wouldn't use it all that often as it does cause alot of browser requests, again be sure all are optimized so the download time is very minor.  Something to look into is using sprites (I know it wasn't the question) these are very useful for images that don't really matter to SEO of the site (buttons, arrows, bullets, etc.  The big thing anymore is download speed you want to keep the images cached, optimized and as minimal bandwidth as possible.  If your page takes too long to load then your users will leave, that should drive your image create more than best-practices.

Comment: If I had a large background image that I create in PS and it involves alot of layer styles, is it better to save it as a jpeg and use it as a whole than slice it?

Comment: hmm, very good question. Yes I would probably say to save it as optimized as possible.  .png might be better.  I generally stay away from complex backgrounds. Mainly because of the load time and trying to put together a sliced background image doesn't sound very fun.